# Floor Weight Question for Aquarium

Tags: floor, joists, load-bearing

I am building a reef tank in my living room, it's in the corner of the house, and as you can see from the drawing, it is sitting on 5-floor joists. The house is less than 10 years old and the joists are 16ft long before the beam.

Will this be enough to safely support 2500-3000 lbs? The tank weighs 2500 plus people.

[image: drawing]

Comment: this is the point where you talk to a structural engineer and don't trust random people on the internet with the integrity of your residence

Comment: How far apart are the floor joists? 16 inches on center? Are they 2x8 joists, 2x6, etc?

Comment: This question cannot be answered by anyone using the information provided.  The existing load as well as the design loads (both static and dynamic) must be considered before adding an exceptional weight such as your proposed reef tank.  Please hire a licensed structural engineer to evaluate your plans and make appropriate recommendations.

Comment: Your sketch implies a relatively small footprint for the tank, which makes for a very high "pounds per square foot" (or newtons per square meter) loading, far beyond what your house was built to for normal loadings for code. Hire the engineer. If you insist on not hiring the engineer to tell you exactly **what** to do **where** to get it **right**, you'll want to add some beams and columns under the tank area. The advantage of using an engineer is you can get those exactly right, rather than *guessing* what you need and *hoping* it works. Also: are you in a seismic hazard zone?

Comment: How many people are you putting in your fish tank?

Comment: The usual pattern is one hapless associate for effect, followed by Mr. (or Ms. we hear) Bond and leaving the house in time for Mr. or Ms. Bond to escape from whatever people eating thing lives in the tank, I believe, rather than sticking around long enough to be sure. Be sure to pet the cat.

Comment: If 5' across the joists the 5x16x40lbs per sf = 3200 lbs total for that 80 sf. and you're dealing with a concentrated load. You are definitely in the range of needing an real engineer to look at actual conditions to verify no structural flaws are present.